# No data filtering in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, having

Why does the number of records increase when adding a 'country_id' constraint?

My first request. 30 entries are displayed here :

```
SELECT 
    app_id,
    sum(installs)
FROM 
    application.app
    JOIN sales.app_total ON sales.app_total.app_id = application.app.id
WHERE 
    sales.app_total.date BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-07'
    AND application.app.app_market_id = 4
    AND country_id = 100
GROUP BY 
    app_id
HAVING 
    CAST((sum(sales.app_total.revenue_usd) * 0.2) / 1 AS FLOAT) >= 0
    AND CAST((sum(sales.app_total.revenue_usd) * 0.2) / 1 AS FLOAT) <= 0
```

My second request. 8 entries are displayed here:

```
SELECT
    sum(installs)
FROM 
    application.app
    JOIN sales.app_total ON sales.app_total.app_id = application.app.id
WHERE 
    sales.app_total.date BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-07'
    AND application.app.app_market_id = 4
GROUP BY 
    app_id
HAVING 
    CAST ((sum(sales.app_total.revenue_usd) * 0.2) / 1 AS FLOAT) >= 0
    AND CAST((sum(sales.app_total.revenue_usd) * 0.2) / 1 AS FLOAT) <= 0
```

UPD: table app_total
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yXsD.png)

The whole problem started with the fact that the condition 'and revenue_usd = 0' does not work in the next request. It adds up all the fields, even those that have income. Any thoughts why?

```
SELECT
    country_id,
    sum(installs),
    sum(revenue_usd) as rev
FROM
    sales.app_total
    JOIN application.app ON application.app.id = sales.app_total.app_id
WHERE
    date = '2023-05-01'
    AND application.app.app_market_id IN (4)
    AND revenue_usd = 0
GROUP BY 
    country_id
```

Comment: Can you possibly add sample data as well please

Comment: Without data it's hard to check. However, the HAVING is rather strange and the fact you group by app_id but don't return the app_id is another red flag for this query: You get results that you can't validate. Not to mention the usage of a FLOAT. Advise: rewrite the entire query and create some unit tests to see if the query returns correct results.

Comment: @Nate1zn ок, i added table

Comment: Please don't link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question as editable text